# Light Fixture Stopped Working After Replacing Its Three-Way Switch

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, light-fixture, multiway-switch

I have a halogen light fixture that is powered by a three-way switch at the top of the stairs and another three-way switch at the bottom of the stairs. After I replaced both switches with [new 3-way switches](https://www.homedepot.com/p/100078412) the light fixture stopped working.

The old switches were connected with black, white, and red wires and I replicated the same connections with the replacement switches. I used a [voltage tester](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000EJ332O) and turned off the breaker box switch before touching the wiring.

The light fixture has left and right ends that hold the small halogen light bulb. After several hours of testing the best outcome I can achieve is the right end outputting power but the fixture will no longer power the light bulb.

Here's some info:

**Switch 1**
[image: Switch 1]

- Located at the top of the stairs
- Bottom right black screw connected to black wire
- Top right bronze screw connected to red wire
- Left bronze screw connected to white wire
- Green screw connected to ground wire
- Removed the new switch, turned on the breaker box, and the voltage tester showed only the black wire is hot
- Tried replacing the new switch with the old one with no success
- Tried replacing the new switch with a couple other new switches with no success

**Switch 2**
[image]

- Located at the bottom of the stairs
- Bottom right black screw connected to black wire
- Top right bronze screw connected to white wire
- Left bronze screw connected to red wire
- Green screw connected to ground wire
- Both switches turned on shows black, red, and white wires are hot
- Removed the new switch, turned on the breaker box, and the voltage tester showed none of the wires are hot
- Tried replacing the new switch with the old one with no success
- Tried replacing the new switch with a couple other new switches with no success

**Light fixture**
[image: Light fixture]

- Using the above wiring and placing the voltage tester in each end of the bulb bracket shows the right end is hot but the left end is not
- None of the wiring connections below would power the fixture's bulb
- Uses a [J Type 118mm Double Ended 120 Volts 150 Watt T3 Halogen Bulb](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00WC1XAH0)
- Tried two different light bulbs

With this wiring I observed these results (only difference is the switch 2 red wire is hot or not):

- Switch 1 on and switch 2 on: both sets of black, white, and red wires are hot
- Switch 1 on and switch 2 off: switch 1 black, white, and red wires are hot and switch 2 black and white wires are hot and the red wire is not
- Switch 1 off and switch 2 on: both sets of black, white, and red wires are hot
- Switch 1 off and switch 2 off: switch 1 black, white, and red wires are hot and switch 2 black and white wires are hot and the red wire is not

I tried several different combinations of left and right bronze screws but none would power both ends of the fixture:

- Switch 1 left white and right red and switch 2 left white and right red
- Switch 1 left white and right red and switch 2 left red and right white
- Switch 1 left red and right white and switch 2 left white and right red
- Switch 1 left red and right white and switch 2 left red and right white

I tried removing the light fixture so I could check its wall wiring with the voltage tester but I started stripping one of its screws so I stopped.

A few questions:

- If all six wires are hot (black, white, and red on both switches) is the circuit complete?
- Should both ends of the light fixture's bulb compartment be hot when the circuit is complete?
- Could the left side of the light fixture have a blown fuse?
- When I get the fixture removed if I have a complete circuit will the black, white, and red wires be hot?

Anything else I can try?

New Photos

[image]
^ Left white wire is cold
[image]
^ Left red (!) wire is hot
[image]
^ Left black wire is cold
[image]
^ Right red wire is cold
[image]
^ Right white wire is cold
[image]
^ Right black wire is hot
[image]
^ On the left, a working three way switch that powers three basement lights and, on the right, Switch 1
[image]
^ Close up of their wires
[image]
^ Traveler wires for the working three-way switch
[image]
^ The top left black wire with the white jacket is tied off with the bottom right black wire (next to the stranded ground copper wires) and the switch 2 traveler wires exit through the bottom right of the box
[image]
^ The ends of the two black wires from the previous photo twisted together with a yellow wire connector
[image]
^ The fixture's right terminal is hot but the bulb is not working
[image]
^ Upstairs right switch turned on and the fixture terminal's right wire is hot
[image]
^ Upstairs right switch turned on and the fixture terminal's left wire is cold
[image]
^ Tied off white neutral wires in the back of the box are hot with the switch on
[image]
^ Fixture black wire is hot with the switch on
[image]
^ Fixture white wire is cold with the switch on

Comment: Have you tried it with a bulb?  On a light fixture, one terminal will be hot and the other is neutral.  Both terminals will not be hot.  Also, those voltage detectors are meant more to double check for voltage for safety and are not great tools for diagnosing problems - just use a multimeter.

Comment: Think of electricity flowing in loops.  It comes from the electric panel on a black or red hot wire, but it has to get back to the same panel after it goes through a fixture or appliance.  It goes back through the white neutral wires.  A hot wire by itself can't do any work unless it can connect back through a neutral.

Comment: @JPhi1618 thanks for your comments. Yes, I tried three different light bulbs but none would light up. Anything else I can try?

Comment: When you replaced the switches do you pay attention to screw colors on the switches? Or did you attach the wires in the same orientation?

Comment: @Tyson I took pictures of both switches and connected the replacement switches using the same wires connected to the same screws. When that didn’t power the light bulb I tried swapping the red and white wires but no luck then either. Could I have fried the fixture?

Comment: "same screws" does not distinguish between "selecting screws by position" and "selecting screws by color".  Your question discusses positions at length and doesn't say boo about screw color, so I assume the former.

Comment: @Harper the screw color, screw location, and corresponding wire are listed under “Switch 1” and “Switch 2” above: “Bottom right black screw connected to black wire, Top right bronze screw connected to red wire, Left bronze screw connected to white wire.”

Comment: However that's the configuration that *doesn't* work.

Comment: you should have power on only one side of the lamp .... if both sides are connected to the hot wire, then the lamp will not light

Comment: @jsotola unless  you're in the Philippines lol... they are transitioning from a North American split-phase to Euro style single phase, and houses in split-phase territory are simply wired hot-hot only. Neutral is not used.

Comment: I doubt you fried the fixture.  Since this is a halogen there are no electronics associated with the fixture, so it's just wires and ceramic lampholder.

Answer (score 9):

### DON'T try *random stuff* when you get stuck

Trying to replace actual knowledge with "throw things at the wall and see what sticks" *is a fatal error* when dealing with electrical equipment.  Why?  The entire strategy is based on stopping when you find "the" combination that works.  Actually, many combinations will work *and also kill you*.  The only way to avoid those is skill, so the right thing to do is pause, research and measure.

I'll grant you *if you are only connecting to 3-way switches*, you can't go too far wrong - but nonetheless, this habit is so dangerous in almost any other context, that I want to address it.

### *Position* of wires on multiway switches is useless

I assume you're changing switches and receptacles for color or style.  In that, the most common gotcha  (other than *broken-off tabs* on receptacles) is assuming 3-way switch builders do you any favors by keeping screw positions consistent.  "They do not" is the understatement of the year. The only useful indicator is screw color.

Related, electrical wiring is not very well color-coded, and multi-way switch circuits are *worse than not color-coded at all*.  I for one mark wires obsessively, so the next person has a chance of understanding the circuit.

Probably easiest to just "do it the old fashioned way".  **Travelers are always in the same cable** (and are never ground wires obviously).  Switch 2 is no help at all.  So we look at switch 1.  Only two are in the same cable (I can't see, you can) -- *gotcha!*  Those are the travelers.  Now, knock wood, that cable is continuous to switch 2, in which the same 2 colors will be the travelers there. (If it stops anywhere intermediate, all bets are off, and *this is why I mark wires*).  **Buy a 5-pack of colored tape, and mark all travelers yellow.** There is no need to distinguish travelers from each other.

Then, travelers go on the brass screws.  The remaining wire goes on black.

***Edit:*** Looking at your photos in switch box 1, it seems clear the *travelers* are white and red.  Wrap them with yellow electrical tape.  Most likely they are also white and red at switch 2 (that's not 100% sure but it's the thing to try first.)

### The light should have 1 terminal hot

Lights are the ultimate load, and in mains electrical, most loads connect between hot and neutral (unless you dealing with North American 240V or in the Philippines where everything is that). Therefore there should only be "hot" on 1 terminal, not both.

---

***Edit:*** If the right lamp wire is energized, then *most likely* the 3-way set is delivering power correctly (it may still be wired wrong for the switches to work as intended).

If power is present at the right, and still it doesn't light, then it's a) burned out bulb.  b) burned out socket.   Or c) the neutral wire has a problem.  There'd be no reason for the latter to happen, given that you don't touch the neutral when replacing 3-way switches.

Your next test is to fit the light bulb and test the left socket.  If the left socket suddenly reads "hot", that means there's something wrong with the neutral wire. Otherwise you have a bad lamp or socket.

---

To answer your questions directly:

- If all six wires are hot, you need to file a warranty claim on your 3-way switches!  The only other possibility here is that your voltage tester is picking up *phantom voltage*.
- Both sides of the lamp should never be hot.  If it is, and the bulb is in it, that indicates a broken neutral wire. That left side is surely neutral.
- Neutrals don't have fuses. Their only overload protection is being monogamous to **one** hot, which is fuse/breaker protected. MWBCs are engineered to allow 2 hots to share 1 neutral. All other sharing creates overloads.
- Neutrals should never be hot.   Travelers are in pairs; one will be hot.  Switched-hot will only be hot when the switch is on. Always-hot is *I'll give you 3 guesses*.  Notice I haven't mentioned a color yet.  That's because colors don't necessarily correspond to functions.  This is why I wrap tape around wires: in *my* world, switched-hot is red or blue, travelers are yellow *in pairs*.   Here is how your box looks in my world.

[image]

(the thin lines are just to make clear which wire is which; the meat of what I do is the band of  yellow.) The purple dashed line is a "Chinese Wall" between the left side and right side switches. Because nothing crosses, *nothing is allowed to cross*. That is relevant if you put a smart switch on the left: it *must not* steal neutral from the right.

Comment: Precisely! If both terminals were hot, they would be at the same potential and therefore no current would flow.

Comment: @Harper thanks for you reply. This is very helpful.

I added a few new photos at the end of my post and captioned them.

The light was working (the bulb lit up) before I replaced the switches so I know it’s something I did wrong (i.e. I don't think it's an issue behind the wall with the switch 2 travelers).

My question is, since the right terminal of the fixture has power when I flip switch 1 on, why isn't the light bulb working?

Comment: @Harper I'm supposed to disconnect the switches, turn on the breaker, identify the wires that are not hot, turn off the breaker and mark the wires that are not hot with tape (around their jackets), correct?

Comment: @Ryan I completely agree, if the right fixture terminal shows power, I'd expect it to work.  The problem is the left side measurement is ambiguous: it may be tied to neutral or may be disconnected.  Fit the bulb and test again.  If voltage appears at the left side, the neutral is disconnected, *which is weird, because changing 3-ways shouldn't have affected the neutral*.

Comment: @Harper - that makes sense. I've tried a few different combinations tonight and can only get voltage on the right side of the fixture, no voltage from the left side. I've tried three brand new light bulbs and none will light up. I even try to refit the bulb, jiggle it around, nothing works. Could the fixture have died during this switch replacement? Anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure you're measuring properly; that thing is a *non*-contact tester, it only needs to touch an insulated wire and should give a reading.  I imagine there's a high-temp wire exiting the left socket? Similar on right socket?  Touch both with a bulb installed.

Comment: @Harper When the light bulb is installed and the top right switch is turned on the fixture terminal's right wire is hot but the left is not according to the meter (see two new photos above). Does this mean the fixture has a burned out socket? Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan That's sure what it sounds like to me, yeah. If the bulb/socket was intact but the neutral fried, you would see voltage on both sides (because it would be floating the neutral up to line voltage).  Can you put the non-contact tester on the two nutted white wires in the box?

Comment: @Harper I tested the fixture again this morning and BOTH of the fixture's left and right terminal were hot but the light bulb would still not light up. The tied off white wires inside the box were also hot (see new photo). I then turned off the breaker and removed the fixture, turned on the breaker, and the fixture's black wire is hot and the white wire is not with the switch on (see new photos). Do I have a burned out socket? I'll try a new fixture soon.

Comment: If the white wires inside the box were *also* hot, that only means you have a severed neutral between that box and the power source/supply.  Notice what else has lost power, and turn off the breaker to see what else is on the circuit.  The lost neutral must be at the last good point or first bad point (which isn't here).

Comment: @Harper The other items on the circuit, such as the front door light and bathroom light switches, still have power. I also replaced those switches recently but they still work. The only item that lost power is the three-way light switch above. I replaced the light fixture today but the new light fixture still does not output light from its light bulb. Anything else I can try? Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan like I say you have to look very closely at neutral wires, either at the first bad location (e.g. in the back of this box) or at the last good location, e.g. any of those locations that do work.   With the light on, just touch the non-contact tester to the insulated neutral; if it lights, the fault is between you and the panel...

Comment: @Harper sorry, I'm confused. So do I need to turn off the breaker box for this chain, remove and disconnect another light switch or outlet from the chain, turn on the breaker box, and use the meter to test its white neutral wire is hot? If so, what do I do then? Then repeat for the next light switch or outlet? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Great pics Looks like a bad splice to switch.  Or the guy that wired house had his own way of doing it.Most of the time ,black and red are used as travelers White as load out. It seems to be a dead end 3 way splice.  The one box with the problem may be, the one with the 3 wires.White to black screw, red black on brass as travelers.White wire should be made a black color .It is not a grounded conductor.(not neutral).If you did not touch any other switches.Put white on black screw black red on brass, If you did work on other 3 way Should work.and are they the upper switches.  That does not work send pic of the other switches .

Comment: Thanks Robert. Should the hot wire should go in the black screw on the switch?

Comment: I just posted new photos of both sets of three-way switches under the light fixture at the top of the stairs. The left switch's set of wires has a hot red wire and the right switch's set of wires has a hot black wire. Connecting each hot wire to the black screw on their respective switches, and their travelers on the brass screws, does power the fixture's right terminal but it still does not power the light bulb.

Comment: If you  think you are getting  power from the hot wires, and they turn off and on.Up and down ,,Not the switch   ,,..Bad light socket or ,,Pulling wires out loose wire nut in white wires .I think It is light .Should read  120 if you take light off.  Bad socket happens a lot with that light .

Comment: Thanks Robert. I think it has to be the light fixture at this point. I've tried everything else I can think of.

Comment: Take off light check power.

Comment: I have about 10 shop lights like that .And could buy a new light a Walmart 2 bucks, More than new bulb .

Comment: Yes, I'll remove the light fixture tomorrow. Kids are asleep and I don't want to wake them up with my drill lol.

Comment: In your pic, on off the black wires has a nick in it ..Needs repair

Comment: Got the fixture off and added new pictures. Also put electrical tape around the knick in the wire - thanks.

Comment: I replaced the light fixture today but the new light fixture still does not output light from its light bulb. Anything else I can try? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you do not have neutral. Loose wire nut to white wires?